# Can you use requests.get() without HTTPS/HTTP

Tags: python

I have a code that takes a random flag from the Flag Mashup Bot and downloads it:

```
import requests

DIR = 'C:/Users/myUser/Desktop/Flags/'
URL = 'https://flagsmashupbot.pythonanywhere.com/mashup?passwd=fl4gsm4shupb0t'


def download_image(img_url: str, dest_dir: str):
    img_data = requests.get(img_url).content
    with open(dest_dir, 'wb') as file:
        file.write(img_data)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    response = requests.get(URL)

    if response.ok:
        page = response.text
        image_url = page[page.find('data:image', page.find('data:image') + 1):page.find('" download=')]
        name = page[page.find('" download=') + 12:page.find('_FlagsMashupBot.png"')]
        DIR += (name + '.png')
        print(DIR)
        download_image(image_url, DIR)
```

When I run it, I get the following error on line 8:

```
requests.exceptions.InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found for [image URL]
```

When I read about it, I realized that it's because the image URLs from the site don't start with "https://" (or at least that's what I understood).
So, is there a way to use requests.get() without having https at the start of the URL?

Comment: Any troubles in adding a `http://` prefix to the URL ?

Comment: Also, how about you use the bot directly : https://github.com/antooro/FlagsMashupBot ?

Comment: I want to create my own code since I plan on downloading many images into the folder (and I feel more comfortable doing it with my own code). And yes, there is a problem. It just doesn't recognize the URL when I add the prefix.

Comment: Yup, I realised why it wouldn't honour the HTTP/HTTPs prefix, you're making use of href which points to the base64 encoded data instead of url. You can directly dump that base64 data into a file in binary and that'll give you the file. Please note the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you would not get an HTTP/HTTPs based URL is since the data is in href format pointing to the base64 encoded version of the image.
You may use urllib to open up the href download link and save the contents to a file:

```
data = 'data:image/png;charset=utf-8;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAABwgAAASwCAIAAABggIlUAAAABmJLR0QA/wD/AP+gvaeTAAAgAElEQVR4nOzdaZhd92Hf97Pde+fOYGYAzAx2gCBBivsCgqtEUl7piF.......'
response = urllib.request.urlopen(data)
with open('image.png', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(response.file.read())
```